# Why does the writer use 'is' twice in a row here?

Tags: linking-verbs

Why does the writer use 'is' twice in a row here?

> Either the issuer's place of business where the undertaking ***is issued is*** located in a country that has adopted the Convention, or under international conflict of law principles, the law applicable to the undertaking is the law of a country that has adopted the Convention

Answer (score 4):

I'll put brackets in to aid your understanding:

"either (the issuer's place of business [where the undertaking **is** issued] **is** located in a country) that has adopted the Convention, or under international conflict of law principles, the law applicable to the undertaking is the law of a country that has adopted the Convention"

The first "is" relates to "the undertaking" and the second "is" relates to the "place of business".

Answer (score 3):

I think there are some missing commas in the example. Probably just a typo, or perhaps the author thought they'd used too many already. It's a horribly long sentence - a terrible example of English legalese, and it is on the verge of being almost impenetrable.

Here are some extra commas to help break it up a bit into digestible pieces.

> Either the issuer's place of business, where the undertaking is
> issued, is located in a country that has adopted the Convention, or
> under international conflict of law principles, the law applicable to
> the undertaking is the law of a country that has adopted the
> Convention.

I've read it several times over. Still makes hardly any sense to me, but then I'm not a lawyer, just a simple human;)